# AngularJS scope acting weird

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, element

I have table with ngRepeat rows and ngShow columns. Rows are OK, however columns doesn't react to ngShow. Weirdest thing - `angular.element($0).scope()` returns `undefined` in Chrome console while inspecting the table element.

How can it be that the scope is OK at one point in time but doesn't exist in another? (console.log doesn't are not helpful - shows correct scope while anywhere in the app.)

**edit**: There is a brief moment where an early-set interval can catch (on decent PC) a glimpse of `angular.element($0).scope()` existing. Before and after that single moment it's `undefined`.

Comment: pls try to setup a fiddle and add your code to the question

Comment: http://plnkr.co/
or
http://jsfiddle.net/ Please :)

Comment: OR use Batarang extension  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en